# Unable to load library 'libskiasharp' desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, skiasharp, livecharts

[image]I have this problem " Unable to load library 'libskiasharp' " when i want to show Cartesian Chart in our desktop application.

I use LiveCharts2.

The problem doesn't appear when I run the application from Visual Studio.

Comment: Remember to deploy the skisharp assemblies.